# Which python packages should I install globally, in a virtual environment, or both?

Tags: package-management, apache2, python

I have a Django project and Wordpress website on a single Apache web server. I use virtual hosting to host them together.

I made a virtual environment for my Django project and installed WSGI module there. My Django project smoothly works in the virtual environment.

However, when I started working on my Wordpress website, the website stopped working because my Apache could not start without WSGI globally installed. So, I globally installed WSGI module.

Do I need to globally install all the packageds installed in a virtual environment on my machine? What are good customs?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different python applications used on your system coming from sources files (not from Ubuntu packages), I recommend you to keep your virtual environment. You can set virtual environment in Apache configuration with WSGIPythonHome directive.

More information:
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#embedded-mode-single-application

Comment: I properly configure WSGI daemon process, and still I needed to globally load mod-wsgi to run Apache while I was developing my Wordpress website. Did not I need to?